# Laptop charger on high performance making "crackling" sounds

Tags: laptop, battery, charger

I've read multiple threads about how a "crackling" noise coming from a laptop charger is worrisome, but I recently I found that my laptop charger makes this sound only when my computer is running a high intensity program. Otherwise, the charger is completely silent and has no problems. Since I got this charger less than a year ago I am a bit reluctant to buy a new one. I was just wondering should I go and buy a new charger or is the noise normal?

Answer (score 0):

Crackling means that electricity is arcing on high demand.
You should listen carefully to ensure that the noise is coming from the
cable or from where it's plugged-in to the computer, and not from inside
the computer.

Crackling can be caused by the cable, but equally well from the plugged
port. Below are some suggestions to check both.

- Ensure first that the port and cable plug are totally clean from dust,
  rust and everything else
- Verify that the pins in the plug are straight and the connection is good
- Connect to another wall outlet, to check if the problem is with the
  electrical outlet
- If the charging is via USB, try another USB port
- Clean the power connector using a suitable product
- Try another charger, if you can loan one.